# Send token only if the first transaction was successful solidity (SWAP),

Tags: solidity, tokens, swaps

I'm learning how to do swaps with solidity and I have 2 questions:

1. Should I verify the allowance of both wallets that will do the swap with the respective token? Also, should I verify the balance, or is it enough with the allowance and the safeTransfer?
2. I'm calling safeTransfer twice and I want to understand how it works: if one is successful, and the other is not, does the transaction revert and the tokens return?

```
    function swap(uint amount) public payable {
        require(
            BUSD.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= estateInfo.supply,
            "BUSD allowance too low or insufficient"
        );
        require(
            token.allowance(owner, address(this)) >= estateInfo.supply,
            "Token (NOTIFY TO DEV) allowance too low or insufficient"
        );
        require(
            BUSD.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= amount,
            "BUSD too low or insufficient"
        );
        require(
            token.balanceOf(owner) >= amount,
            "Token too low or insufficient"
        );
        

        _safeTransferFrom(BUSD, msg.sender, owner, amount);
        _safeTransferFrom(token, owner, msg.sender, amount);

        emit tokenSwap(true);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically checking for the allowance and the balance in your case is not necessary. During the safeTransfer the tokens will check if allowance and balance are correct and:

- if allowance and balance correct: safeTransfer will not revert
- if allowance or balance incorrect: safeTransfer will revert

To the second question, only one of these safeTransfer reverting will revert the whole transaction (unless you're doing something weird on top). So you should be good.